# How can I specialize argument/data types inside an instance function? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I have defined and am implementing a class to help test functions which normally perform filesystem IO. As seems to be reasonably standard, I've declared IO to be an instance of this class, and defined a new `Monad` to keep the state of the fake filesystem data when testing. The functions I want to test can either be run within IO or within this new `FSStateMonad`. The fake filesystem data itself is kept inside an object I call `FSState`.

I've got the normally maximally-complicated situation mostly working: `withFile` takes a path, an `IOMode`, and a handler function which takes a handle to the open file and with which a function can be called to append data to the file in question. The problem comes at the end, because I need to do some post-processing on the state after the handle has been notionally closed. At that point, I am having problems specializing the variables inside the class function to the types needed in the fake-filesystem monad.

Here's what I hope is the right amount of code to illustrate what's going on and the approach I've taken. The full minimal example that actually passes syntax checking and loads via `stack` is [here](https://gist.github.com/unprolix/6ad061d92a07ae9c036bfae3dafa94fb).

```hs
newtype HandleMap = HandleMap (Map String BSL.ByteString) deriving Show
newtype FileMap = FileMap (Map String BS.ByteString) deriving Show
data FSState = FSState { _handles :: HandleMap
                       , _files   :: FileMap
                       } deriving (Show)

class Monad m => MonadWriteHandler m where
  type MWHandle m
  type MWResult m
  withFile :: FilePath -> IOMode -> (MWHandle m -> m r) -> m r
  hPutBSL :: MWHandle m -> BSL.ByteString -> m (MWResult m)

instance MonadWriteHandler FSStateMonad where
  type MWHandle FSStateMonad = FSHandle
  type MWResult FSStateMonad = FSState

  hPutBSL (FSHandle h) bs = return $ FSState { _files = mempty
                                             , _handles = HandleMap $ M.fromList [(h, bs)] }

  withFile path WriteMode handler = do
    completed <- handler $ FSHandle path
    -- fixup would happen here
    return completed
  withFile _ _ _                  = error "Read not implemented"

  closeHandles :: FSState -> FSState
  closeHandles FSState { _files = fs, _handles = hs} = FSState { _files = fs <> closeFSHandles hs, _handles = mempty }
    where
      closeFSHandles (HandleMap hm) = FileMap $ M.map BSL.toStrict hm
```

I'd like to be able to call `closeHandles` from within the `withFiles` definition for `FSStateMonad` but the compiler doesn't like it. In the case above, the error message complains that it wants a type annotation because the type of `completed` is ambiguous, but when I provide one it doesn't like it, even though `type MWWResult FSStateMonad` is `FSState` as defined in the instance. If instead I use a version of `closeHandles` defined outside of any instance, it complains because `completed` must be of type `r` and not `FSState`. I've also tried specializing the defintion of the instance's `withFile` function, to no avail.

I have a feeling that I'm either approaching this in some unintentionally broken way, or I'm missing a basic language technique. I'd appreciate guidance!

Comment: Huh, the gist compiles for me as is... I just checked again. I'm using ghci 8.6.4 via stack. I don't want anyone to waste time! I'll pare down the stack setup and post the whole minimal directory, and I'll also explore what `ScopedTypeVariables` provides--thanks!

Comment: Uh, the gist does work now, I didn't have a package installed.

Comment: Doh! I just replaced the gist link with one that includes the extra files necessary for it to work under stack ;)

Comment: After a brief look, it seems that your `withFile` is too specific, sicne it does not work for arbitrary return types `r`, but only for `r = FSState`. Your `FSStateMonad` is defined as an identity monad, so I'm unsure about how you are planning to carry state around (it looks unfeasible). I'd have expected some definition like the state monad in `Control.Monad.State`.

Comment: Thanks! I will look at it again with an eye towards that.